# React-Router PrivateRoute is not working. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, private

I've got react-redux private router not working.
It is just showing me a blank page of the route I am trying to access.
And my states are not loading at Redux Dev Tools.
Can it also be the problem of HashRouter?
My PrivateRoute Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {Router, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  }
  isLoggedin = () => {
    return this.props.isAuthenticated;
  };

  render = () => {
    let { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Router
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          this.isLoggedin() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : props.location.pathname === "/" ? null : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
          )
        }
        />
    );
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
})

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute));
```

My App where I am wrapping my Routes to make it private:

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'
import {loadUser} from './actions/authActions'
import PrivateRoute from './components/auth/PrivateRoute'


class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        store.dispatch(loadUser())
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <HashRouter basename="/">
                    <Navbar />
                    <Route exact  path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/aeons" component={AeonsList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/carrefours" component={CarrefoursList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/farmers" component={FarmersList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/foodhalls" component={FoodhallsList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/grands" component={GrandsList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/heros" component={HerosList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/primos" component={PrimosList} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/ranchos" component={RanchsList} />
                </HashRouter>
            </Provider>

        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Route`, not `Router` when defining your privateRoute component.

`import {Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43949554/2873538)